# Atomic directive openmp with loops

Tags: openmp, atomic, directive

Is it possible to use the atomic directive for a single for loop

For example:

```
#pragma omp atomic
for (i=0;i<5;i++)
A[i]++;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, this is not possible.

Technically speaking, the `atomic` construct applies to an access to a specific storage location. The following statements are valid expressions for `omp atomic` (for C/C++) as per 2.13.6 of the standard:

- If *atomic-clause* is `read`:

  ```
  v = x;
  ```
- If *atomic-clause* is `write`:

  ```
  x = expr;
  ```
- If *atomic-clause* is `update` or not present:

  ```
  x++; (and -- as well as prefix forms)
  x binop= expr;
  x = x binop expr;
  x = expr binop x;
  ```
- If *atomic-clause* is `capture`:

  ```
  v = x++; (and -- as well as prefix forms)
  v = x binop= expr;
  v = x = x binop= expr;
  v = x = expr binop= x;
  ```

  In this case, some specific structured blocks are allowed:

  ```
  {v = x; x++;}
  {x++; v = x;}
  ```

  And all combinations of the update forms with `v = x`

The standard further specifically limits `x` and `v` to scalar types, so vector / array types are not allowed, even if you were to implement an `operator=`.

If you want to make this update to appear atomically, you must protect the entire update and all accesses to the `A` with a critical region, a lock, or ensure otherwise that no concurrent access is performed and memory visibility is guaranteed. I cannot give a more specific recommendation without more specific code.